# How to prevent popup from getting close by escape key

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript window.open popup, and I want to prevent popup from getting close by itself when the user presses the ESC key. I can't figure out how to hook the keydown event (and on what object?) so that I can catch the ESC key.

Please help me out!.

Comment: Do you plan to *disable* the ESC key altogether or involve some functionality after the key press?

Comment: The `Esc` key does not close windows in any browser I know.

Comment: Hi Basher, The real picture is  when i enter my website address in the browser a Java script popup form will display only after submitting the form the user can enter the site. but what happening now is by pressing the escape key the popup is getting closed. any option to restrict this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var myWindow = window.open();

myWindow.onkeydown = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 27){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
};
```